# What is wrong with my configuration Spring Security and token JWT?

Tags: java, jwt

I have a problem and I don't know what to do, the problem is probably with the configuration, but this is my first spring project.
I have a login method that generates a token, but when I want to perform some task as a logged-in user, there is an authorization problem.

Postman: `The request was a legal request, but the server is refusing to respond to it. Unlike a 401 Unauthorized response, authenticating will make no difference.`

Logs:

```
2023-09-13T14:25:54.951+02:00 DEBUG 27392 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /customer/login
2023-09-13T14:25:54.980+02:00 DEBUG 27392 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /customer/login
2023-09-13T14:25:55.417+02:00 DEBUG 27392 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-09-13T14:26:25.703+02:00 DEBUG 27392 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /customer/loggedCustomer
2023-09-13T14:26:25.715+02:00 DEBUG 27392 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-09-13T14:26:25.717+02:00 DEBUG 27392 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2023-09-13T14:26:25.724+02:00 DEBUG 27392 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2023-09-13T14:26:25.727+02:00 DEBUG 27392 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-09-13T14:26:25.728+02:00 DEBUG 27392 --- [nio-8085-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

Code:
Login function and generate token:

```
@PermitAll
@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<String> loginCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerLogin customerLogin) {
    CustomerLogin storedCustomerLogin = customerLoginService.findPasswordByEmail(customerLogin.getEmail());
    if (storedCustomerLogin != null) {

        String hashedPasswordFromDatabase = storedCustomerLogin.getPassword();
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        if (passwordEncoder.matches(customerLogin.getPassword(), hashedPasswordFromDatabase)) {

            String token = jwtTokenService.generateJwtToken(customerLogin);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(token, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            logger.info("Attempting to log in customer with email: {}", customerLogin.getEmail());

            return new ResponseEntity<>("Invalid credentials", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    } else {
        logger.error("Error during customer login for email: {}", customerLogin.getEmail());

        return new ResponseEntity<>("User not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

}

Configuration spring security:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 public class SecurityConfig {

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf()
            .ignoringRequestMatchers("/customer/register", "/customer/login", "/admin/**", "/common/**", "/customer/**")
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                    .requestMatchers("/customer/register", "/customer/login", "/admin/**", "/common/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            );
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

}

Function jwt token:

```
 @Service
 public class JwtTokenServiceImpl {
CustomerService customerService;
SecretKey key = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256);

@Autowired
public JwtTokenServiceImpl(CustomerService customerService) {
    this.customerService = customerService;
}

public String generateJwtToken(CustomerLogin customerLogin) {

    return Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject((customerLogin.getEmail()))
            .signWith(key)
            .compact();

}

public String extractEmailFromToken(String token) {
    Claims claims = Jwts.parserBuilder()
            .setSigningKey(key)
            .build()
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody();

    return claims.getSubject();

}

public boolean isAuthenticated(String token) {
    try {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(key)
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
        Date now = new Date();
        return now.before(claims.getExpiration());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Function display logged client data:

```
@GetMapping("/loggedCustomer")
public ResponseEntity<Customer> getDataLoggedCustomer(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String token) {

    String email = jwtTokenService.extractEmailFromToken(token);

    if (email != null) {
        Customer loggedCustomer = customerService.findByEmail(email);
        if (loggedCustomer != null) {
            logger.info("The client with email address {} has been successfully authenticated.", email);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(loggedCustomer, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
    logger.error("Error authenticating client with address e-mail: {}", token);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);

}
```